# Devise: Tracking user visit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, user-tracking

On my app I have to track each user visit.

The way I imagine it is that I'll have a new table users_tracking with at least 3 fields: `id, user_id, visited_at`.

If there is no row for the user on the present day I'll add one otherwise I do nothing.

But I'm not sure where and how I should implement the code doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the ahoy `gem`. It manages visitors and visits (with `ahoy-events` gem).

Ahoy: http://ankane.github.io/ahoy/

Comment: Thanks, I looked into this gem before posting and I actually use groupdate and chartkick but it seems a little bit too much for what I want